# Google analytics time on page estimation

Tags: google-analytics

Does google analytics count the time the user stays on a web page when the browser is minimised or the user has switched to another tab and website or for some reason the webpage is not on focus?

Answer (score 1):

Time on site is measured between the first pageview of the session and the last pageview of the session.  Thus it *does* include the time during which the page did not actually have the attention of the user.

It *does not* include any time the user spent on the last page they viewed.   So if the user only views one page, there will be zero time on site, even if they spent 20 minutes reading that page.

[Here is a good article](http://cutroni.com/blog/2012/02/29/understanding-google-analytics-time-calculations/) that explains the calculations in more detail.